# sql with case in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2008 - this is my initial SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE FLDID = 1111
  AND FLDFNAME = 'XXXX' 
  AND FLDLNAME = 'YYYY' 
  AND FLDDEPT = 'SCIENCE'
```

Need to check the `FLDDEPT` only if `FLDREGISTERDATE` is smaller than a certain date, otherwise no need to check the department condition.

Tried using below but, getting error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'

How to fix this??

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE FLDID = 1111
  AND FLDFNAME = 'XXXX' 
  AND FLDLNAME = 'YYYY' 

CASE 
   WHEN FLDREGISTERDATE < '2019-10-01' 
      THEN AND FLDDEPT = 'SCIENCE' 
      ELSE '' 
END
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Boolean expressions.

```
...
WHERE FLDFNAME = 'XXXX'
      AND FLDLNAME = 'YYYY' 
      AND (FLDDEPT = 'SCIENCE'
            OR FLDREGISTERDATE >= '2019-10-01'
             OR FLDREGISTERDATE IS NULL)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

A WHERE clause needs a condition. A `CASE` expression can only output a value. Instead you can do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE FLDID = 1111
  AND FLDFNAME = 'XXXX' 
  AND FLDLNAME = 'YYYY' 
  AND FLDDEPT = CASE WHEN FLDREGISTERDATE < '2019-10-01' THEN 'SCIENCE' ELSE FLDDEPT END
```

Now that last condition will return `TRUE` when `FLDREGISTERDATE` is >= `2019-10-01` since `FLDDEPT=FLDDEPT`. In the case where `FLDREGISTERDATE < '2019-10-01'` then it will test for `FLDDEPT = 'SCIENCE'`.